# ClickOnce required to run setup?

Tags: vb.net

Could anybody advise me if we need to install ClickOnce application on client's computer, if we need to run a setup file made with ClickOnce?

Also, when we publish, how can we specify if we want to use ClickOnce or Windows installer?

Thanks 
Furqan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install anything in the client if you're going to deploy your app using ClickOnce.

If you run the publish wizard, the wizard will ask you "How will the users install the application?" If you select "From a CDROM or DVDROM" option then a setup.exe will generate in the selected path.

Comment: By publish wizard you mean what we run from 
Build >>>> Publish <Project Name>   ????
But this does not allow user to select installation path or make desktop / program group icons.  Am I right?

Comment: Right Click  your proyect->properties. You select the icon in the application tab. Then in Publish tab->options->manifest you can select "create desktop icon". Program group and installation path will be selected by the user during the installation (not pretty sure of this).